# Correct terminology for confidence intervals

Tags: probability, statistics

In Portuguese people speak of "intervalo unilateral à direita/bilateral" and Italians speak of "intervallo unilaterale destro/bilaterale" when referring to $P[S_1 ≤ \theta ]= \gamma$ and $P[S_1 ≤ \theta ≤ S_2]=\gamma$,S being the statistic(s) that are used as bounds. What's the correct spelling/terminology in English?

Comment: Maybe one-sided and two-sided confidence intervals?

Comment: Thanks! I actually checked now on the web: it is right-sided confidence interval $\gamma$% (or $(1-\alpha)$%) interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct spelling: Right-sided confidence interval γ% (or (1−α)%) interval